# Add an App not showing publishing feature list and libraries for a custom master page

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

Add an App not showing the publishing feature list and libraries for a custom master page created. Checked out with the site settings for the publishing feature activation as well

Answer (score 0):

```
Add the below code to your Master Page after the div: <div class="ms-breadcrumb-top"> but inside <div class="ms-breadcrumb-box ms-tableCell ms-verticalAlignTop"> as follows:
```

[image]